# Is storing pointers in std::vector ruining it's advantage of continuous memory storage

Tags: c++, containers

`std::vector` stores it's elements continuously in memory as opposed to `std::list`. This gives the `std::vector` better performance when iterating over the elements as everything is neatly packed vs jumping all around the memory when iterating a `std::list`.

Problem is most of the time I store smart pointers in vectors for polymorphism or for sharing these objects with other parts of the code. Since each object is now allocated dynamically I assume they end up in different memory locations. Is this defeating the purpose of using a `std::vector` and essentially turning it into something like a `std::list`? Is there anything that can be done to fix this?

Comment: The purpose of `std::vector` is to simplify storing elements. Whether you put pointers in there or objects, that's exactly its purpose, without defeating it.

Comment: If you measure, I think you will find that iteration over a vector or over a list (or most any other iterable container) will not make any noticeable difference.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg perhaps you should try measuring it. You would be surprised... :)

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes you are right, updated my question title. Hopefully makes more sense now. @Joachim you are right, but I always read that one of the biggest advantages of `std::vector` is the continuous memory storage along with random indexing at O(1).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg alternatively, check out [this](http://bulldozer00.com/2012/02/09/vectors-and-lists/). Iterating over a list requires an indirection and a probably cache miss for every node. A vector just requires incrementing a memory address and all but guarantees a cache hit.

Comment: Bjarne talking about vector vs list at 44 minute mark and saying how vector is much faster than list and why, one of the reasons why I am asking this question too. 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't pointless.

When iterating over a `std::list` of possibly smart pointers, you jump to nearly random points in memory on each iterator increment.  When accessing, you again jump to a nearly random point in memory.

If you did the same iteration-access in a `std::vector` of possibly smart pointers, you would only jump to a nearly random point in memory once.

How can you make this less painful?

If you are using a `std::shared_ptr`, remember to do `std::make_shared` so the ref counter and the data are in the same allocation, reducing cache misses.

If you are just using it for polymorphism, in theory you could instead store something like a `boost::variant` (or a `union` of the various types together with something that says what the type is), which permits multiple types of variables to exist at the same address (one at a time, naturally).

Comment: Never used `placement new` but would it be possible to use it to allocate the members of the `std::vector` so that they are placed continuously in memory. Or am I asking for more trouble than it's worth? :)

Comment: You could create a pseudo-`boost::any` (restricted to be children of your base class `T`) with what I might call the "small object optimization" that uses placement `new` for subclasses of a given class.  And by "small class" I mean something modestly larger than the base class.  Or you could mess around with allocators.

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that the biggest advantage of `std::vector` over `std::list` is that indexing is an O(1) instead of O(n) operation. What you're talking about is a more second order optimization. Also, you're always free to store your own objects all in one big array and then you wouldn't be jumping around as much (if cache purposes is what you're thinking about).

Comment: +1 for example deleting every dynamically allocated element in a vector: `for i - vector.size() delete vector[i];` would be a good use case this

Comment: I would disagree: `std::deque` also has O(1) indexing, but you should avoid using it for the same reason you should avoid using `std::list`: non-trivial performance hits from lack of contiguity.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` would still have locality advantage compare to `std::list` as you iterate through it and call some virtual methods on each polymorphic object.

now since you are potentially calling different functions each time, it is a good idea to sort the objects by their actual type, to avoid instruction cache miss.